# Why does this simple login script work in Tampermonkey but not Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have this tiny little script that I run inside Chrome using Tampermonkey and works great.

However, when I use it in Firefox with Greasemonkey, it shows up on the active list, meaning its matching the page but it doesn't actually execute the code. I know it has to be a simple something I am overlooking but its not hitting me.

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer();},100);

function myStopFunction()
{
    clearInterval(myVar);
}

function myTimer()
{
    var p1 = "Login";
    var p2 = "mode=login";
    var x = document.body.innerHTML;

        if (x.match(p1) && x.match(p2)){
            document.documentURI = "/ucp.php?mode=login";
        }
    myStopFunction();
}
```

**Script Logic/Function**

1. I am using a timer to prevent the script from triggering over and over in a permanent loop.
2. It simply detects if I am logged into a phpBB forum or not, if not send me to the login page so I can log in.
3. I am using document URI so that the location of the original is preserved so upon login, it takes me right back to it.
4. Often phpBB when you log in, it will take you back to the index page so this preserves my original intent of going to the actual link.

This script works perfectly and as expected on Chrome using TM but on Firefox using GM it doesn't trigger, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

From [the Firefox spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentURI):

> (`document.documentURI`)
>   Returns the document location as string. It is **read-only** per DOM4 specification.

And, indeed, [**the latest spec**](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) still specifies that this attribute must be read only.

If Chrome lets you write this property, then that is non-standard behavior and maybe a bug.

Use `location.assign()`, or `location.replace()`, or just programmatically click the login button -- which often preserves the target page.

Comment: My savior. How are you buddy. Thanks for that, I cant' believe I missed that. I now remember, that was one reason I was using TM/Chrome for several of my scripts, including this one. Let me play with the two you mentioned and see what I come with and I will post back either resolved or not. Thanks again.

Comment: Well as promised I tried and `assign()` doesn't work, loses the link after its done and unfortunately the built-in gui doesn't take you back to the link that brought you there when you click on login, otherwise I wouldn't bother with this :( I have tried so many different things that by the time I was done it was like so complicated instead of being simple, I gave up. If you think you can help me with this quickly without too much effort on your part, I'd be grateful but I don't want you to waste time if its not an easy solution, not worth wasting your time. Thanks buddy.

Comment: The question was "Why does this script work on Chrome but not Firefox". That question has been answered. ... There are usually phpBB-specific ways to callback the original page, but phpBB is not relevant to this question apparently ;) and we'd need a link to the specific website to be absolutely sure.  The general case is possible but: more work, site-specific, and beyond the scope of what's asked here.  Ask a new question for a workaround.

Comment: Yeah I now buddy, just don't think its worth the hassle of getting people on this problem. I will keep hacking away at it until I figure it out, didn't want to make it phpBB specific by the way ;) because I have other similar sites that can benefit from the concept if I expand the parameters so I wanted to keep it as general as possible, then expand it. So I will see if I can get the basic functionality cross browser working and then go from there. Thanks.